# How to separate my different data entries to match with my legend entries?

Tags: r, legend, r-plotly

I have tried to create a plotly graph in R Studio so I have the option to hide certain legend entries if/when I want.

However, the issue I have come across is all of the values from my dataset have been added under 1 legend entry despite my data supposedly meant to have 5 separate entry points. If I haven't yet been clear in describing my problem hopefully it becomes clearer with the images I provide.

My original graph -

[image: 1st line graph]

My attempt at a graph with a interactive legend -

[image: 2nd line graph]

The first line graph is how it is supposed to look like. However, the second line graph seems to have joined up all the years together in 2015.

My code is as follows -

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)

twit1 <- read.csv("//ecfle35/STAFF-HOME$/MaxEmery/Social media analysis/Twitter/December/engagement rate.csv", comment.char="#", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

twit1$Months = month.abb

twit1$Months = factor(twit1$Months, levels = month.abb)

# Manipulate years as you were doing

twit1$Years <- twit1$Year
twit1$Years <- as.factor(twit1$Years)

# Plotting the line graph

p <- plot_ly(twit1, x = ~Months, y = ~Engagement, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = '2015') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~2016, name = '2016') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~2017, name = '2017') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~2018, name = '2018') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~2019, name = '2019')
```

My dataset -

[image]

Comment: You were doing great ... until you included an image of your data. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. (And I generally don't do transcription on SO.) Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Are you intending to use `tidyr` and `plyr` here? It does not appear that either package is being used in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the year to the color, rather than adding new traces.

```r
plot_ly(twit1, 
        x = ~Months, 
        y = ~Engagement, 
        color = ~Years, 
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'lines')
```

See this example for more: https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#mapping-a-color-variable

Comment: Thank you! Adding this code did exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my or Armando's answer so that others with the same question may better find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `ggplotly` in order to turn a ggpplot graphic into a plotly graph:

```r
library(plotly)
library(ggplot)

p <- ggplot(twit1, aes(x = Months, y = Engagement, color = Years)) + 
       geom_line() + 
       labs(title = "The rate of growth for Twitter engagements", 
            x = "Months", 
            y = "Engagement")

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding this code did exactly what I wanted to do.